# Changing the location of site/user/login

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

There's a login page at `http://site.com/user/login` Is there a clean way to change the the path of that page to something like `http://site.com/log` so that `/user/login` leads to a 404 page.

Comment: What would be the point of this? I tried this once before in Drupal 5, but it wasn't pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_menu_alter to do this. Alternatively you can use a path alias if you just want it to loom pretty.